# Problems and theories in CS that uses Fibonacci numbers

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I want to know problems and theories where Fibonacci sequence is used and where we have some possibility to use Fibonacci numbers. I have found that-

1. In counting number of steps for Euclidean algorithm, 2. [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap), 3. [Fibonacci search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_search_technique), 4. Fibonacci numbers are complete; means we can write any number as sum of Fibonacci numbers(Fibonacci basis) etc.

Is there any other applications of this sequence in CS. Please share if you know any other.